Cypress tests failing after updating Keycloak to version 24.0.2
I recently updated my Keycloak image from jboss/keycloak to quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2 after jboss/keycloak was removed from Docker Hub. Previously, everything worked fine with jboss/keycloak, but after the update, I'm encountering issues with my Cypress tests.
Most of the tests are timing out or experiencing network errors. While using jboss/keycloak, I consistently saw around 33 tests passing out of 50. However, with quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2, only about 6 tests are passing in CircleCI, and locally the Cypress tests are not even running as the container becomes unhealthy.
I've noticed that one of the containers in CircleCI is marked as unhealthy, although it doesn't seem to be directly causing the Cypress test failures.
Has anyone else experienced similar issues after updating to Keycloak 24.0.2? Are there any known solutions or workarounds for resolving these Cypress test failures? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
After updating the health check configuration for the adi-adi-auth-1 container to use curl as follows:
healthcheck:
test: ['CMD', 'curl', '-f', 'http://localhost:8080']
interval: 30s
timeout: 10s
retries: 3
I still encounter the issue of the container being marked as unhealthy during local testing. Despite this configuration, the container fails the health check with the error message:
dependency failed to start: container adi-adi-auth-1 is unhealthy
This occurs even though the health check appears to be correctly configured and the curl command returns successfully when tested manually.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Guess, you might start with "/auth" part being removed from keycloak urls.

yes i have tried that and re-run the cypress on local the container fails and this is the error message i get on the terminal
[+] Running 4/6
✘ Container adi-adi-auth-1             Error
dependency failed to start: container adi-adi-auth-1 is unhealthy
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
